# I want to use $fetch in a Nuxt3 plugin to update Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm a beginner working on a login authentication application using Nuxt3 and Rails API. I'm facing challenges with a process in Nuxt3's plugins.

When a logged-in user reloads the page, the authentication information in the Pinia store gets initialized. Therefore, I'm trying to create a custom plugin that fires on the initial load. I want to use $fetch to get data before rendering, keeping the authentication information in the Pinia store, and preventing hydration errors for a smooth user experience.

While the POST to Rails is successful, when I check Nuxt logs, I see that VueRouter is indefinitely fetching api/v1/auth_token/refresh, preventing other processes from taking place. This endpoint doesn't exist in Nuxt, causing an error.

I'm looking for a way to exclude api/v1/auth_token/refresh from VueRouter or prevent this infinite loop in some other way. Any advice would be appreciated.

#Nuxt3 serverlog

```
2024-03-07 05:46:45 plugins refreshTokenInit
2024-03-07 05:46:45 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/auth_token/refresh"
2024-03-07 05:46:45 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/auth_token/refresh"
2024-03-07 05:46:45 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/auth_token/refresh"
2024-03-07 05:46:45 global middlewara
2024-03-07 05:46:45 FetchError: [POST] "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth_token/refresh": 404 Page not found: /api/v1/auth_token/refresh
2024-03-07 05:46:45     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2024-03-07 05:46:45     at async $fetch2 (file:///app/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.00501375.mjs:261:15)
2024-03-07 05:46:45     at async refresh (/app/plugins/refreshTokenInit.ts:10:5)
2024-03-07 05:46:45     at async initFunc (/app/plugins/refreshTokenInit.ts:30:22)
```

#Nuxt3 :app/plugins/refreshTokenInit.ts

```
import { useAuthStore } from '~~/stores/auth';

//If a cookie refresh token is present on page reload or initial access, set the user to be logged in.

export default defineNuxtPlugin( () =>{
    console.log("plugins refreshTokenInit")
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    const auth = useAuthStore();  
    const refresh = async() =>{
        await $fetch(
       
        'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth_token/refresh',
          {
              method:"POST",
              credentials: 'include', 
              body:{},                             
              headers:{
                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 
                  'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.auth.token}`,                                                                
              },                
          }
          ).then(response =>{
            auth.setAuth(response)
            console.log(response)
          }).catch(error=>{
              console.log(error)
          })    
    }    

    async function initFunc(){
        const response = await refresh()
    }

    initFunc()
     
})
```

DockerCompose

```
services:
  db:
    # Use the latest image
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine
    # Set important environment variables for the database
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
      PGTZ: UTC
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    # Mount host files for container usage
    volumes:
      - ./api/tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    # Specify the base Dockerfile for building the image
    build:
      context: ./api
      # Pass environment variables to the Dockerfile
      args:
        WORKDIR: $WORKDIR
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      API_DOMAIN: "localhost:$FRONT_PORT"
      BASE_URL: "http://localhost:$API_PORT"
    # Mount host directory into the container
    volumes:
      - ./api:/$WORKDIR
    # Depend on the db service to ensure it starts first
    depends_on:
      - db
    # Expose ports for the API service
    ports:
      - "$API_PORT:3000"
    tty: true

  front:
    build:
      context: ./front
      args:
        WORKDIR: $WORKDIR
        API_URL: "http://localhost:$API_PORT"
    volumes:
      # Optimize reading from host to container with caching
      - ./front:/app:cached
      # Place node_modules volume in the container for optimization
      - nuxt_node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "$FRONT_PORT:3000"
      - "24678:24678"
    tty: true
    environment:
      - port=$FRONT_PORT
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - api
    # Start the container with npm
    command: sh -c "npm run dev"
volumes:
  nuxt_node_modules:
```

Nuxt 3.10　（port8080）　mode:SSR
Rails 7.1.0 （port3000）
Docker

① I attempted to fetch the BASE_URL from the config file in plugins, but it seems that it might not be loaded when the plugin is triggered. I also tried using an absolute path, but it had no effect.

```
   //   config.public.apiOrigin+'/api/v1/auth_token/refresh',
        'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth_token/refresh',
```

② I considered whether the issue could be related to Nuxt's default port being 3000, so I changed the Rails port to 3001. However, this did not seem to have any impact.